# racket slideshow image specify size

Tags: image, racket, slideshow

In racket slideshow, it is possible to include an image with the `bitmap` command, like this:

```lisp
#lang slideshow

(slide
 #:title "Presentation"
 (t "Introduction")
 (bitmap "image.png"))
```

But nothing in the documentation tell how to specify the size of the image (width and height). Does someone know how to do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`size-in-pixels`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/slideshow/Primary_Slide_Functions.html#%28def._%28%28lib._slideshow%2Fbase..rkt%29._size-in-pixels%29%29)?

Comment: Nope, size-in-pixels doesn't allow to specify a size, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find how to do it, you need to use the "scale" function of the `pict` package (already imported by slideshow), like this:

```lisp
#lang slideshow

(slide
 #:title "Presentation"
 (t "Introduction")
 (scale (bitmap "image.png") 3))
```

In this example it will triple the size of the image. Of course you can also reduce the size with a fraction instead of an integer.